# Cannot clone git repo un EC2 iNSTANCE

Tags: amazon-ec2, git-clone

I used the following command and tried to clone a repo but unfortunately the following error pops up. I cannot go further

**`ubuntu@ip-add-rr-ee-ss:~$ git clone https://github.com/repo/file.git`**

`Cloning into 'file'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repo/file.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com`

Comment: please provide me with the output of `cat /etc/resolve.conf`.

Also, did you somehow disable ingress to UDP 53 and TCP 443?

Comment: result of /resolv.conf

# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could not resolve host

This must be due to DNS issue on your EC2 instance (I can see that you're using Ubuntu here)

1. You can try to use `curl` to test the connection to that URL first
2. Check the DNS configuration: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`
3. If possible, you
   should replace your current DNS setting with others DNS like **google**
   (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4)
4. Try to edit that file: `vi /etc/resolv.conf`
5. You
   should insert/edit the following into:
   ***nameserver 8.8.8.8 

   nameserver 8.8.4.4***
6. Save the file by clicking `[Esc]` and type `:wq`

Comment: @testermoving no problem bro :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem once I added the following to my outbound connection for my group security setting:

```
Type: All traffic
Protocol: All
ip: 0.0.0.0/0
```

This also fixed my sudo yum install issues too.